# What are the intended use cases for Remote Blob Storage (RBS)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

Microsoft's two main sources on RBS do not mention SharePoint explicitly:

- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg316768(v=sql.105).aspx
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/remote-blob-store-rbs-sql-server

However, aside from those top two search results, it seems that most of the other questions, sample code (excluding Microsoft's toy code on Codeplex), and third party providers are tailored towards SharePoint. What types of implementations were intended for this package? Does it work to support more generic solutions, or is it meant as an upgrade to larger SharePoint instances of SQL Server?